# Using XPath to select certain nodeName

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I followed the tutorial on W3Schools.

http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

It says:

> nodename  Selects all child nodes of
>   the named node
>
> bookstore Selects all the child nodes
>   of the bookstore element

and here's my code

bookstore.xml:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <bookstore>
    <book>
      <title lang="eng">Harry Potter</title>
      <price>29.99</price>
    </book>
    <book>
      <title lang="eng">Learning XML</title>
      <price>39.95</price>
    </book>
    </bookstore>
```

the php file:

```php
    <?php
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("bookstore.xml");
    if(!$xml)
    { 
    echo 'bad';
    }else
    {

    $res = $xml->xpath("//bookstore");

    when I use $res = $xml->xpath("bookstore");
    $xml_res1 = $res1->asXML("booklist.xml");
    }
    ?>
```

It only returns an empty array.
I want to select all of the `<book>` elements only (not to include the `<bookstore>` and the `<?xml version?>` header)

In the W3Schools example, the "//bookstore" can select all the child nodes of the bookstore element.

Can anybody tell me why I got an empty array? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
/*/book
```

**or even**

```
/*/*
```

**Of course, you may also use**:

```
/bookstore/book
```

**or even**

```
/child::bookstore/child::book
```

Given the provided XML document, all the above expressions select exactly the wanted nodes -- all `book` elements in the document.

**Always try to avoid using the `//` abbreviation** as it may result in very inefficient evaluation.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev: could you look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478324/build-a-text-from-html-using-xpath?

Comment: @Fran: I cannot understand anything from that question -- even in what language the code is written. I don't think it contains anything XPath related -- otherwise I would have answered it.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev: basically, he has to exclude the html tags. Using the xpath exp //text() works except that the empty lines are not retrieved.

Comment: @Fran: This still isn't an XPath issue. He has to invoke his XML parser with such parameters that will prevent it from discarding white-space-only text nodes, or if he has modify rights on the XML document itself, he can put an `xml:space="preserve"` attribute on the top element.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev: He receives that hml from a server: the empty lines are "translated" with <p class="c4 c1"><span class="c7"></span></p> for example. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: @Fran: [Re: the empty lines are "translated" with `<p class="c4 c1"><span class="c7"></span></p>`] Sorry, Don't know what this possibly could mean :( If you mean that he wants an XPath expression to create (non-existent) text nodes for him, this is impossible only with XPath -- XPath is a query language for XML -- as such it only selects existing nodes -- it cannot create new nodes.

Answer (score 1):

That statement should be: **Selects all child nodes with this name**.

That's why it's called **name test** in specs [1](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#node-tests) [2](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#NT-NameTest).

If you want `book` elements:

```
/bookstore/book
```