# Build a text from html using xpath

Tags: xpath

I receive an html like that below from a server. I rebuild the textual part by using the XPath exp @"//text()" and appending the "nodeContent" value to a string. The code is something like this:

```
for (int i=2; i<[resultXPathQuery count]; i++) {
    [mytext appendString:[[resultXPathQuery objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"nodeContent"]];
    [mytext appendString:@"\n"];
}
```

I obtain:

```
Line 1
line 2
line 3 
line 4
```

How could I build the textual part also considering the empty node?

I would to obtain:

```
Line 1
line 2

line 3



line 4
```

---

```
<html><head><title>A title</title><style type="text/css">
ol{margin:0;padding:0}p{margin:0}
.c0{font-size:12pt;background-color:#ffffff;font-family:Times New Roman}
.c6{width:432.0pt;background-color:#ffffff;padding:72.0pt 90.0pt 72.0pt 90.0pt}
.c7{color:#aaaaaa;font-family:Times New Roman}
.c3{color:#0000ee;text-decoration:underline}
.c5{color:inherit;text-decoration:inherit}
.c2{font-size:12pt;font-family:Times New Roman}
.c4{height:12pt}.c1{direction:ltr}
body{color:#000000;font-size:12pt;font-family:Times New Roman}
h1{padding-top:12.0pt;line-height:1.0;text-align:left;color:#000000;font-size:24pt;font-  family:Times New Roman;font-weight:bold;padding-bottom:12.0pt}
h2{padding-top:11.25pt;line-height:1.0;text-align:left;color:#000000;font-size:18pt;font-family:Times New Roman;font-weight:bold;padding-bottom:11.25pt}
h3{padding-top:12.0pt;line-height:1.0;text-align:left;color:#000000;font-size:14pt;font-family:Times New Roman;font-weight:bold;padding-bottom:12.0pt}
h4{padding-top:12.75pt;line-height:1.0;text-align:left;color:#000000;font-size:12pt;font-family:Times New Roman;font-weight:bold;padding-bottom:12.75pt}
h5{padding-top:12.75pt;line-height:1.0;text-align:left;color:#000000;font-size:9pt;font-family:Times New Roman;font-weight:bold;padding-bottom:12.75pt}
h6{padding-top:18.0pt;line-height:1.0;text-align:left;color:#000000;font-size:8pt;font-family:Times New Roman;font-weight:bold;padding-bottom:18.0pt}</style>
</head>
<body class="c6">
<p class="c1"><span class="c2">A title</span></p>
<p class="c1 c4"><span class="c2"></span></p>
<p class="c4 c1"><span class="c2"></span></p>
<p class="c1"><span class="c7">Line 1</span></p>
<p class="c1"><span class="c7">line 2</span></p>
<p class="c4 c1"><span class="c7"></span></p>
<p class="c1"><span class="c7">line 3</span></p>
<p class="c4 c1"><span class="c7"></span></p>
<p class="c4 c1"><span class="c7"></span></p>
<p class="c3 c2"><span class="c1"></span></p>
<p class="c1"><span class="c7">line 4</span></p>
</body></html>
```

**EDIT**

Really, I noticed that the html can be more "complicated", so it's not enough selecting all the span elements or p elements. Moreover, more span elements can appear in the same p element, so in that case I have not to create a new line in my string.

This is the body of a more complicated returned html:

```
<body class="c13">
<p class="c5"><span>gfgfgfd</span></p>
<p class="c1"><span></span></p>
<p class="c5 c10"><span>ghhgfhgfh hghg hgkfhjgk ghjgkh ghjgjhg gjhjg gjhj gjhgjhgjhg gfhjkgjg jghjgfhjgf fghfj jghfj fghjggf jhgjgjgkjg</span></p>
<p class="c1 c10"><span></span></p>
<p class="c4"><span>gfgfgfd</span></p>
<p class="c4"><span>f</span></p>
<p class="c4">
     <span>gfdgfdg</span>
     <span class="c7">hg</span></p>
<p class="c4"><span class="c7">ghgfhgfh</span></p>
<p class="c4"><span class="c7">gfhgfhgf</span></p>
<p class="c5">
     <span class="c7">hgfh </span>
     <span class="c0">gfdgfg</span></p>
<p class="c5"><span class="c0">fgfdgfdgfd</span></p>
<p class="c5"><span class="c0">gdfgdfgfd</span></p>
<p class="c5"><span class="c0">gfgf</span></p>
<p class="c1"><span class="c0"></span></p>
<p class="c5"><span class="c0 c8"><a class="c12" href="http://www.google.com">www.google.com</a></span></p>
<p class="c1"><span class="c0"></span></p>
<p class="c5"><span class="c0">fgfdgfdg</span></p>
<p class="c5">
     <span class="c0">fgffgfdgfg</span>
     <span class="c0 c11">gfgfdgfd fgd fd</span>
     <span class="c0">fdgfdg</span></p>
<p class="c5"><span class="c0">fgfdgfdgf</span></p>
<p class="c5"><span class="c0">gfd</span></p>
<p class="c5"><span class="c0">gfgf</span></p>
<p class="c1"><span class="c0"></span></p>
<p class="c5"><span class="c0 c8"><a class="c12" href="mailto:….">...</a></span></p>
<p class="c1"><span class="c0"></span></p>
<ol class="c9" start="1">
<li class="c3"><span class="c0">gfgfd</span></li>
<li class="c3"><span class="c0">gfdgfd</span></li>
<li class="c3"><span class="c0">gfdgfd</span></li>
<li class="c3"><span class="c0">gdfgfd</span></li>
</ol>
<p class="c1"><span class="c0"></span></p>
<p class="c5"><span class="c0">hgfhgf</span></p>
<p class="c5"><span class="c0">gfhgfh</span></p>
<p class="c5"><span class="c0">hgfhgf</span></p>
<p class="c1"><span class="c0"></span></p>
<ol class="c2" start="1">
<li class="c3"><span class="c0">gfhg</span></li>
<li class="c3"><span class="c0">hgfh</span></li>
<li class="c3"><span class="c0">hgf</span></li>
</ol>
<p class="c1"><span class="c0"></span></p>
<h1 class="c5 c15"><a name="h.kafwflosthlg"></a><span class="c7 c14">hgfhgfh</span></h1>
<p class="c1"><span class="c6"></span></p>
<p class="c1"><span class="c6"></span></p>
<p class="c1"><span class="c6"></span></p>
</body>
```

I'd need an XPath expression that selects p, h1, h2,..., h6, li elements, and considers the inner textual part in such way that new line and empty lines are properly detected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the example above you can use `//span` which will return all the `<span>` elements regardless of their contents. It looks like you are doing some other filtering also because //text() should also return your CSS block and `A Title` from the `<title>` and first `<span>`.

Comment: yes, in the for statement the var i begins from 2, so I leave out the inline css and the title. I have to some some other tries to check if the server (GDocs) always uses a form like that. In case, how can I use //span together with //text()? Moreover, do you know how take span elements without other elements in it, that is for example take all span elements that not contain an img element?

Comment: @Objnewbie - `@"nodeContent"` should return the text value of the node (in this case `the text value of `span`). You will have to experiment to see if it is an empty string or nil when there is no text value. To get a only the span that don't have img elements use something like `//span[not(img)]`.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed that the returned html can be more "complicated" than that above (the first) as you can see in the second example.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use a regex for this one:

1. Grab all the content between the body tags (you can also do that with XPath)
2. Replace `</p>` by `</p>\n`
3. Strip tags